# Norm of the momentum 4-vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, momentum, vectors, metric-tensor

The norm of the momentum 4-vector is

$\mathbf{P}.\mathbf{P}$ $= (\gamma mc, \gamma mv).(\gamma mc, \gamma mv) = \gamma mc^2 - \gamma mv^2$

But why is $\gamma mc^2 - \gamma mv^2 = mc^2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have to replace the erroneous $\gamma$ by $\gamma^2$ (and similarly $m$ by $m^2$) in the inner product and because
$$\gamma^2 m^2 c^2 - \gamma^2 m^2 v^2 = \gamma^2 m^2(c^2-v^2)=\dots$$ 
and
$$\gamma^2 = \frac{1}{1-v^2/c^2} =\frac{c^2}{c^2-v^2} $$ 
and $c^2-v^2$ from the explicit factor cancels against the denominator of $\gamma^2$, while $c^2$ from the numerator survives, so we get
$$\dots = m^2 c^2$$